# jquery addClass if div width is less than

Tags: jquery, width, addclass

```
var section = $('.section');
var width = section.width();
if (width < 960)
    section.addClass('.section-slim');
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this?
I'm not getting the added class.

Answer (score 7):

remove the *dot* in the class name:

```
section.addClass('section-slim');
```

---

More on [***CSS Grammar***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)